# Throwing exception in async method with preprocessor directive

Tags: c#, exception, async-await, c-preprocessor

I have a task to clean the project of compiler's warnings. Currently I am working on cs file that is used in solutions for ASP.NET and Xamarin. There I have a method:

```
    public override async SomeReturnTypeItem LoginAsync()
    {
#if __MOBILE__
        throw new NotSupportedException("Windows authentication is not supported in mobile version");
#endif
    //some code
    }
```

In Xamarin solution I have a warning that code under `#endif` is unreachable. If I replace `#endif` with `#else` and put `#endif` to the end of method, I receive a warning  that method lacks `await` operator and will run synchronously. How can I make this method free of warnings?

Comment: What did you expect? The code *is* unreachable if `__MOBILE__` is set - an exception and any code after it won't execute . If you don't want the warning, remove the code, or use an `#else` directive

Comment: If you are getting the warning "method lacks await operator"` you should not have the `async` keyword at all, get rid of it for both versions.

Comment: Am I safe in assuming "some code" contains an `await`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I used is to cheat compiler.

```
    public override async SomeReturnTypeItem LoginAsync()
    {
#if __MOBILE__
        bool isMobile = true;
        if (isMobile)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("Windows authentication is not supported in mobile version");
        }
#endif
        //some async code
    }
```

Visual Stuidio says that async code is unreachable heuristically, but compiler is satisfied. Of course it is a little bit ugly, but it works. However thank you guys for trying to help)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest fix would be

```
public override async SomeReturnTypeItem LoginAsync()
{
#if __MOBILE__
    throw new NotSupportedException("Windows authentication is not supported in mobile version");
#else
    //some code using await
#endif
}
```

But that's probably not exactly the behaviour you want, because if `__MOBILE__`
 is defined, the method will return a faulted `Task` instead of throwing right away. The difference can sometimes prove very big, mostly if you store the `Task` for later use instead of awaiting it right away (for instance if you want to start several tasks and let them run concurrently).

To remedy this, you should put the exception throwing code in a method and the async implementation in another:

```
public override SomeReturnTypeItem LoginAsync()
{
#if __MOBILE__
    throw new NotSupportedException("Windows authentication is not supported in mobile version");
#else
    return LoginAsyncImpl();
#endif
}

private async SomeReturnTypeItem LoginAsync()
{
    //some code using await
}
```

Of course, if you're not using `await` at all, you just shouldn't mark your method as `async` in the first place!

```
public override omeReturnTypeItem LoginAsync()
{
#if __MOBILE__
    throw new NotSupportedException("Windows authentication is not supported in mobile version");
#else
    //some code not using await
#endif
}
```

Note that a non-async code can still return a `Task`. That's useful for instance if you implement an interface or base class that make some methods return task so that the implementation could be really asynchronous, but your specific implementation happens to be synchronous.

```
public override Task SomeMethodAsync()
{
    // do some  synchronous stuff
    return Task.FromResutl(true);
}
```

Comment: I think the 2nd part of this answer is the best solution.

Comment: But the 1st part is wrong (or incomplete) because, as mentioned in the question, he already tried that and it gives a different warning.

Answer (score 0):

It's kinda ugly, but you could do this:

```
    public override
#if !__MOBILE__
    async
#endif
    SomeReturnTypeItem LoginAsync() {
#if __MOBILE__
    throw new NotSupportedException("Windows authentication is not supported in mobile version");
#else
    //some code
#endif
    }
```

This is assuming you actually have the `await` keyword somewhere in "some code". If not, then you should just remove `async`.

Or, you can simply use a `#pragma` directive to suppress the warning:
[#pragma warning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/441722ys.aspx)

Comment: The problem isn't `async` it's that any code after a `throw` *is* unreachable

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It is meant to be used together with his modification: using `#else...#endif`. I've edited to make that more clear.